# Interpolation of 17 data points - temperature data

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, interpolation

I have 17 location points here in Iceland: weatherstation points.

It's a 10-year, month-to-month, composite of temperature values for each station which means 120 values for each station. 2040 values overall. Since I only have 17 station I only have 17 values visible on my map.

What I want to do is interpolate these points to create a temperature map for the area and I want to be able to compare them, f.i. compare june for every year and make a map of that - compare june-sep for each year - compare december for 5 of those 10 years etc. I basically want to be able to compare what I want.

The distance between each point varies but the area is fairly small so only a few kilometers between stations.

When the interpolation is done I hope to be able to do a time animation from the data.

This is a school project. I am attending The University of Iceland.

So, which method should I use and how?

Thanks in advance.

Einar Ingi

Comment: What software do you have available to use for your analysis?

Comment: @Baltok, Einar Ingi tagged the question with arcmap.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a quantitative export, but it seems like [Spline interpolation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Spline/009z0000006q000000/) might be a good fit.

> Polynomial functions are regarded as a good method for interpolation
>   of monthly  and yearly climate elements but are less suitable on
>   higher temporal resolutions like days and  hours

This paper goes over the various interpolation methods and how they relate to temperature data.

http://www.knmi.nl/bibliotheek/knmipubIR/IR2009-04.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using ArcGIS 10 and I think the license is ArcEditor.

Answer (score 1):

Similar answer to artwork21.

I answered a question a while back and the same answer seems applicable here.

[How to Create Contours for Zonation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21298/how-to-create-contours-for-zonation/21346#21346)

> I've not used ArcGis, however I have achieved a similar result with
>   SAGA GIS which is an Opensource GIS application.
>
> http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html
>
> Use Gridding to interpolate the point data (B-Spline, Cubic Spline,
>   Multi Level B-Spline...) and then using "Contour Lines from Grid" to
>   convert the grid to contours.
>
> I know its not a direct answer to your question but it giveas you
>   options.

Basically follow the directions above but ignore the contour lines from gird part and you have a nicely interpolated grid data set for each month, and its done using SAGA which is opensource.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GDAL and its powerful [gdal_grid command](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html) for creating regular grids of scattered data.

For example this command will create an interpolation raster in GTiff from a shapefile named "points.shp" storing the values in a field named "value" using the inverse distance to a power algorithm:

```
$ gdal_grid points.shp output.tif -zfield value -ot Float64 -l points
```